# Reading from file, computing and writing to new file

Tags: c

I need to read the numbers from a data file and output the results to a corresponding letter grade and write these grades to a new file. I managed to get the program to create the new file but it doesn't seem to be writing the grades to it. Can anyone point out where I have gone wrong? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double n1=0.0, n2=0.0, n3=0.0;
    double sum1=0.0, sum2=0.0, sum3=0.0;
    double avg1,avg2,avg3;
    int count=0.0;
    char grade;
    FILE *inFile;
    FILE *outFile;

    inFile = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (inFile == NULL){
        printf("\nFailed to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while(count<1001){
        fscanf(inFile,"%lf %lf %lf",&n1,&n2,&n3);
        sum1 += n1;
        sum2 += n2;
        sum3 += n3;
        count ++;
        }
    avg1 = sum1/1000.00;avg2 = sum2/1000.00;avg3 = sum3/1000.00;
    printf("\nSum of Column 1 is: %lf\n", sum1);
    printf("\nAverage of Column 1 is: %lf\n",avg1);
    printf("\nSum of Column 2 is: %lf\n", sum2);
    printf("\nAverage of Column 2: %lf\n",avg2);
    printf("\nSum of Column 3: %lf\n", sum3);
    printf("\nAverage of Column 3 is: %lf\n",avg3);


    outFile = fopen("grades.txt", "w");
    while(fscanf(inFile,"%lf %lf %lf",&n1,&n2,&n3)!=EOF){
        fscanf(inFile,"%lf %lf %lf",&n1,&n2,&n3);
        outFile = fopen("grades.txt", "w");
        fprintf(outFile,"%char\n",&grade);
            if(n1||n2||n3 < 60)
            grade = 'F';
            if(n1||n2||n3 >= 60)
            grade = 'D';
            if(n1||n2||n3 >=70)
            grade = 'C';
            if(n1||n2||n3 >=80)
            grade = 'B';
            if(n1||n2||n3 >= 90)
            grade = 'A';
            }
    }



fclose(inFile);
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
fprintf(outFile,"%char\n",&grade);
```

has a lot of problems

1. It will write `Fchar` in case the grade was `"F"`
2. It will pass the address of `grade` instead of it's value, while the `"%c"` specifier expects a `char` not a `char *`, this will cause undefined behavior.
3. It will pass `grade` uninitialized the first time.

Enable compiler warnings and you will have to fix a lot and,
don't ignore the value returned by `fscanf()`, read the manual or some reference documentation to understand what the meaning of the return value is.

Comment: Can you explain the %c issue? I looked up char* and it references strings and arrays, something we haven't touched up yet.

Also how would I initialize grade as grade is a character?

Answer (score 1):

The writing to the file is handled by the operating system of your computer.

You open the output file once before the loop and many times inside the loop. Open it only once, before the loop. Otherwise your system may block when you try to open a file for writing that is already open for writing.

You do not close the output file. On many operations systems, that lead to your writing being lost. Add an `fclose(outFile)` after the loop.

And then of course also check iharobs answer.

Answer (score 0):

`if(n1||n2||n3 < 60)`. This is illegal in C you need to compare each value seperately. Somthing like
`if(n1<60 || n2<60 || n3<60)`

Comment: It is not strictly illegal, it just does something different than you want. But that make it even worse. 
It reads more like "if n1 is true, or n2 is true, or n3 is bigger then 60. And in C, a number is true when it is not zero, so all the if-statements will almost always be executed.